# Delete key press capture fails

Tags: vb.net, keyboard

I made some captures on button pressing by the user. I capture the CTRL+V and CTLR+C but I would also like to capture the press of the delete button.

This fails to work for me. I tried debugging to see if my sub gets fired but no success.

What do I need to adjust to capture this event?

```
Private Sub dgvOccurrences_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles dgvOccurrences.KeyDown

    If e.Modifiers = Keys.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.V Then

        PasteFromClipboard()

    ElseIf e.Modifiers = Keys.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.C Then

        CopyToClipboard()

    ElseIf e.Modifiers = Keys.Delete Then

        DeleteSelectedContent()

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The `Delete` key is not a modifier like control or shift. Use `e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delete key isn't a modifier hence `e.Modifiers` won't capture it. Instead you'll need to check the `keyCode`.

Try this clause in your IF statement:

```
ElseIf e.keyCode = Keys.Delete Then
    ' Your code
```